# dGPU passthrough: Is it possible in a Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, nvidia-graphics-card, lenovo-laptop

I own a Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3 15ACH6, which comes with an AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with Radeon graphics iGPU and an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop dGPU.

What I'm trying to achieve is a Kubuntu host OS and a Windows 11 guest OS running in a VM (I'm not sure which VM software to use, though I have heard that KVM and QEMU are good for this purpose) with the dGPU passed through to it.

I have searched quite a bit about this but felt only more confused. Some people mention that this is easier to do on a muxed laptop but I haven't been able to figure out if my device qualifies. I know that it doesn't have a physical mux switch at least.

Some other information that I thought may be relevant is that the BIOS gives the option to "select graphics device" where the two options are "switchable graphics" (default) and "UMA graphics." There is also the option to enable AMD V technology, which is enabled by default.

All I want to know is if this is even possible on my machine. Some insight would be wonderful.

Comment: Which Linux distro, which virtual machine product and which Windows version?

Comment: Actual processor model might be useful too.

Comment: I added the relevant details to my question.

Comment: Short answer as a comment: No, not possible. Switchable graphics as the name implies aren't on at the same time.